# How do I write this algorithm to search for the next question in a question tree?

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-search-tree

I've been struggling to write the correct algorithm for this. So I have a tree of questions that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    question: "Question 1",
    answers: {
      "yes": [
        {
          question: "Question 1a",
          answers: ["A", "B"]
        }
      ],
      "no": null
    }
  },
  {
    question: "Question 2",
    answers: ["I agree"]
  }
]
```

And I have a `responses` object, which could look something like this:

```
[
  { question: "Question 1", answer: "yes" },
  { question: "Question 1a", answer: "B" },
]
```

Or it could be this:

```
[
  { question: "Question 1", answer: "no" },
]
```

And now the code I'm struggling to write is to find out what the next question should be. The above two examples of the `responses` object should both point to the next question being `"Question 2"`.

I'd like to have a function like `getNextQuestion(questions, responses)` which would then hopefully output:

```
{
  question: "Question 2",
  answers: ["I agree"]
}
```

I've figured out how to go *down* the tree, but I can't figure out how to go *up* the tree when that's necessary. Anybody willing to help?

Comment: One should treat plain objects as unordered sets of properties (even though since ES6 there is an insertion order with the newer methods). You should use a (nested) array if questions have an order.

Comment: @trincot Ah, thanks for the tip. I changed it now.

Comment: How would you indicate that after a certain answer to a grandchild-question the next question would be either one level up, or two levels up (i.e. at the root)? Just `null` would not make that distinction...

Comment: @trincot See the answer that I've posted, it seems to be working

Comment: OK, so must I understand you never  have answers that should make not only skip the rest of the questions at the current level, but also those at the immediate parent level? Are you saying I should not look any further into your post?

Comment: Correct and correct. I appreciate your willingness to help though!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I may have fixed it with this code. It's been working okay so far.

```
getCurrentQuestion(questions, responses) {
  if (!responses.length || !questions.length) {
    return questions.length ? questions[0] : null
  }

  let response = responses.shift()
  let question

  do {
    question = questions.shift()
  } while (question.question !== response.question)

  let answer = question.answers[response.answer]

  return this.getCurrentQuestion(answer || questions, responses)
    || this.getCurrentQuestion(questions, responses)
}
```